# Is there a way to scrape website using cheerio if the image that i want to scrape is protected by cloudflare and giving 1020 error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cloudflare, cheerio

I am trying to create a manga scraping website as a personal project and just when i completed the whole website, I got to know that the image cant be scraped or viewed by my website and when i try to go to the link of the image, I got 1020 error stating access denied, Is there any way I can bypass that error without getting the authorization token from the website owner,

If the answer is no, then can anyone explain how the cloudflare is protecting the image from scraping because as far as i know everything that are in frontend can be scraped.

Edit : Here is one of the [image](https://s61.mkklcdnv61.com/mangakakalot/u1/uh918990/chapter_0_prologue/31.jpg) that i want to scrape but when i am opening on browser it is giving 1020 access denied error

Comment: *displayed on the page* does not mean *in frontend*. And no, you can't bypass not having access - if you could, why would anyone pay for cloudflare?

Comment: Can you share what image URL in what web page URL you can't scrape?  You are correct that if a browser can display it, then you should be able to scrape it unless the web page is protected with some sort of authentication that you need to provide as part of the scraping.

Comment: I have updated the question and @KenWhiteYes you are right I clearly dont know enough about cloudflare since then I am reading about it, and about the question I dont get any good source for this thats why I ask this question

Comment: @jfriend00: The "1020 error stating access denied* would seem to indicate that the page is protected with *some sort of authentication*, wouldn't it?

Comment: @KenWhite - Apparently 1020 from cloudfare means it was blocked by a firewall rule.  Not sure what that means in this case.  But, it is absolutely true that if a browser can display it, then it can be scraped as long as the same auth is provided that the browser provided.  The browser is just some random client on the internet, not any different than some scraping client on the internet.  The scraper might have to do a better job at imitating a browser.

Comment: What is a link to a typical web page that contains this image?

Comment: https://mangakakalot.com/chapter/uh918990/chapter_0 I am not sure that this was the site for that particular pic but this also contains images that cant be accessed if you open then in new tab

Comment: @jfriend00 I am sure that this is not because firewall in my laptop because i have checked deactivating it and I get the same error while going to the image

Comment: @Arun - I'm not talking about the firewall in your laptop.  I'm talking about Cloudfare's firewall.  See my answer below for how you can work around it.  This is likely a service feature to keep other non-paying web-sites from direct linking to images of a paying customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that web site, in order to download an image like [this one](https://s61.mkklcdnv61.com/mangakakalot/u1/uh918990/chapter_0_prologue/1.jpg), you need this header on the http request:

```
Referer: "https://mangakakalot.com/"
```

Add that header and then it successfully returns the desired image.  Remove that header and you get an error (403 in this case).

Here's a simple test app:

```
const got = require('got');

const url = "https://s61.mkklcdnv61.com/mangakakalot/u1/uh918990/chapter_0_prologue/1.jpg";

const options = {
    headers: {
        Referer: "https://mangakakalot.com/",
    }
}

got(url, options).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

FYI, if you're wondering how I figured this out, I went to the web page that contains this image.  I looked in the Network tab of the Chrome debugger and found the reference to this particular image where the browser downloaded it.  I then looked at the request to the server to fetch this image and looked at exactly what other headers were on the request.  I added two easy ones (`Referrer` and `User-Agent`) to more accurately mimic the browser.  That changed the response from a 403 to a 200.  Then, I experimented to see if I could remove either of these headers and it worked with only the `Referrer` header.

I'm guessing that the difference between the 403 error here and the 1020 error you saw if you directly to that link in the browser is probably to do with the version of http being used (the browser being more advanced than my nodejs script).  But, the point is you can now download the image in the above script.

Comment: I am understanding what you are saying but I am not sure why we need t give a referer header, tbh I have never seen this header before looks like i need to research a bit for it, thank you for the answer tho, I will mark it as accepted, seems to me this will be answer, 
Thank You

Comment: @Arun - As I said in an earlier comment, it's probably a security feature of Cloudfare to keep other sites from direct linking to a customer's images and thus "stealing" hosting services from a paying customer.