# Requesting Images Returns 403 Response

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm requesting an [Image](https://s5.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/mangakakalot/r1/read_bleach_manga_online_for_free2/chapter_673_father/1.jpg) and It returns a 403 response. I tried using my User-Agent and other ones but It still returned 403. I know it's possible to get this image since [tachiyomi](https://github.com/tachiyomiorg/tachiyomi) uses web **scrapers** to get their images. My current code looks like this at this moment:

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "a user agent"}
res= requests.get("https://s5.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/mangakakalot/r1/read_bleach_manga_online_for_free2/chapter_673_father/1.jpg", headers=headers)
print(res.status_code)
```

Is the way I'm requesting the image wrong? Or are there other parameters/headers I should add?

### Solution:

Instead of using User-Agent as the header do

```
headers = {"Referer": "https://mangakakalot.com/"}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66072659/is-there-a-way-to-scrape-website-using-cheerio-if-the-image-that-i-want-to-scrap)

Comment: I think you should add more parameters. Check the real request in the browser (f12) how it looks like. Some requests got an Authorization header and based on that you will be authenticated.

Comment: @Pulkownik I looked at the request headers for the image and found some interesting parameters. authority, and refer. I tried adding them one at a time and then both but none seemed to work. I'm looking at tachiyomi's repo trying to figure out how they send requests.. it's a bit hard though as it's in kotlin. If I have no choice left I might try asking the developers for advise.

Comment: @Pulkownik Great news! I tried searching stackoverflow for the same problem with this website and turns out there was one! I didn't need to use user-agent, What I should've used was referer. I used "refer" instead of "Referer" and that's why it didn't work the first time.

Comment: Awesome! Generally, what I do in the first step I make a normal request in the browser and see its details in developer tools. There is a great feature when you click on your request (network tab) you can select and copy as curl. Then you can easily check in terminal if it works if yes you have everything.